# Continuous play throughout page loads

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am sure this question has been asked but I can't find anything that suits.

I need continuous audio playback throughout page loads. I do not want to use flash or frames and I know this is possible due to the arise of the next soundcloud. Flash is a pain and frames would destroy my navigation buttons etc. You can't even take a look at soundclouds markup so I really have no idea how they've done it but it's impressive.

I would like to know how soundcloud has done this or a way to do this? To be honest I am intrigued by the new soundcloud and would love to take a look at there code but I'm pretty sure that's not going to happen

Comment: The usual solution is actually to put the entire site into an iframe, and the sound player lives alongside the iframe instead of in it.  There are some JS libraries that allow "navigation-free history" where all back/forward button clicks get captured in JS.

Comment: @cdhowie thanks, I shall look into that. Not sure that that is the best solution. It's 2012, there must be an awesome solution.

Comment: I believe that this is what e.g. Grooveshark does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soundcloud is probably using the new HTML5 history API for their magic. But implementing this is not as easy as putting your site into an iframe.

Here is a really great introduction to the API: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: I do imagine Soundlcoud used this method but since continuous play is essential on my site for the voting system I cannot use this method. I will probably have to go with the frame method as a progressive enhancement is not what this is. Maybe when more browsers support this fantastic html5 feature I shall move to it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently looking at this for a musician site that needs continuous audio playback whilst traversing through the site.  If you are developing with Wordpress, I notice there are a few Wordpress themes that have been recently released to support this.

I have a feeling however that the continuous audio functions in these are supplied via Soundcloud - not 100% sure yet until I have a play with them in the coming weeks.

Comment: You may or may not be affiliated with those links, but it does not really matter; their appearance *seems* spammy. I am deleting them, because that does not reduce the value of your answer.